# MismatchedTokenException when attempting to create query

Tags: java, jpa, antlr, jpql

Assume I have this String (it is a JPQL query - the table and column names are substituted correctly using entity classes)

```
//The actual string is auto-generated, but this is just an example:
String sql =
 "select la.laNo,la.status " +
 "from LA la " +
 "where (la.cc,la.laNo) in (" +
 "select lap.cc,lap.laNo " +
 "from LAP lap " +
 "where lap.paNo = '145'" +
 ")";
```

When I try to do:

```
Query q = org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(sql);
```

I get the exception (for brevity, some lines have been removed):

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select la.laNo,la.status from LA la where (la.cc,la.laNo) in (select lap.cc,lap.laNo from LAP lap where lap.paNo = '145')], line 1, column 48: syntax error at [,].
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(81!=84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1375)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8024] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Internal Exception: MismatchedTokenException(81!=84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.syntaxErrorAt(JPQLException.java:362)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:301)
     ...at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticPrimary(JPQLParser.java:17303)
     ...at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:130)
     ...at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:207)
     ...at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:134)
     ...at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1373)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: MismatchedTokenException(81!=84)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.mismatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.match(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticPrimary(JPQLParser.java:17279)
        ... 32 more
```

The SQL is **syntactically correct**, and can return results correctly when I run it in my database manager. So where might the problem be?

**Update:**
Did some testing and apparently, this works:

```
String sql =
 "select la.laNo,la.status " +
 "from LA la " +
 "where la.cc in (" +
 "select lap.cc " +
 "from LAP lap " +
 "where lap.paNo = '145'" +
 ") " +
 "and la.laNo in (" +
 "select lap1.laNo " +
 "from LAP lap1 " +
 "where lap1.paNo = '145'" +
 ")";
```

**Why not the multiple column select?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPQL does not support arrays with an IN, but this is now supported in EclipseLink 2.5.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2013/06/eclipselink-supports-hql-and-several.html

Answer (score 0):

`createQuery()` expects a JPQL query as argument, and not a SQL query. Use `createNativeQuery()` to pass and execute a SQL query.

Comment: Actually it's supposed to be a JPQL query (the table and column names are substituted using entity classes). How do you do multiple column select in a JPQL query?

Comment: `where (la.cc,la.laNo) in (...)` is not possible in JPQL, AFAIK. Use SQL if you need that.

Comment: There's no JPQL construct for it? :(